# Performance rendering empty React components

Tags: reactjs

I have this message that shows depending of a variable. What is the best way to render this component?

I can do this

```
{foo && 
  <div className='error'>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
}
```

but it makes other components in the UI move a little.

I can do this

```
<div className='error'>
    {foo && <p>Hello</p>}
</div>
```

it makes the UI stable but I don't know how to feel about rendering an empty component.

This approach repeatedly wouldn't create performance issues?

What is best practice?

Comment: can you post it on codesandbox and paste the link here to see how it's making the Ui unstable

Answer (score 1):

> This approach repeatedly wouldn't create performance issues?

It's always better to keep as minimum elements in the DOM as possible. Depends on how many elements you want to keep alive - the performance differences for small numbers of elements will be practically undetectable, but when it comes in hundreds or thousands - you may feel the performance drop.

What's also important, when doing it the second way:

```
<div className='error'>
   {foo && <p>Hello</p>}
</div>
```

If your class `error` includes any margins, paddings or fixed height/width - the element will **not** only be present in the DOM, but **will** also be visible on the website and may affect the rest of your content (may move other elements around). The first option is the safer option, to get rid of the element completely.